# Writing Out to Console as Well as to File

Tags: java, file, file-io

I am trying to get the output of my java program to write to a file.

The user inputs some data which should not be included in the file. When the program responds it should output information to the user, as well as write **SOLELY** the output to a file.

From examples I have begun with this at the top of my driver class:

```
static BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
static String lineFromOutput;
```

This code is in every place where I might receive output from the program:

```
try {
    lineFromInput = in.readLine();
    FileWrite.write(lineFromInput);
} catch (IOException e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

And the class its calling is:

```
public class FileWrite {
    public static void write(String message) { 
        PrintWriter out = null;
        try {
            out = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("output.txt"), true);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        out.write(message);
        out.close();
    }
}
```

It creates the output file, but thats it. None of the output from the program is written.
I've looked over numerous examples and this seems to be the easiest way to get the ball rolling, although I'm open to any other suggestions.

Thanks!

Comment: Where can I find the code for OutputtStreamReader?

Comment: I have changed the code slightly, I was playing around looking for other options and copied that part onto the post. It is supposed to be inputstreamreader

Comment: Please fix code.  You have lineFromInput and lineFromOutput.  Be consistent.  This code should not compile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it should be `InputStremReader` with single `t` in statement below:

```
static BufferedReader in= new BufferedReader(new OutputtStreamReader(System.in));
static String lineFromOutput;
```

As

```
static BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
static String lineFromOutput;
```

**EDIT:** This works fine. **Please make sure you provide the input through input console. Also please note that it reads and write(overwrite) single line ONLY.**

```
    public class FileWrite {
       public static void write(String message) { 
                PrintWriter out = null;
              try {
                  out = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("output.txt"), true);
              } catch (IOException e) {
                  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                  e.printStackTrace();
              }
                out.write(message);
                out.close();
        }

       public static void main(String[] args){
           String lineFromInput;
           try {
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                                            new InputStreamReader(System.in));
                lineFromInput = in.readLine();
                FileWrite.write(lineFromInput);
                in.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
           }
       }
     }
```

**EDIT 2:**  Updated program for multi-line inputs. **Its not best way to open and close file each time to write, but I am just trying to make your program work with minor changes.** Let me know, if you need suggestion to avoid repeated opening/closing of the output file.

Change Highlights:

1. Read lines until "exit"(change the word as desired) is received in input
2. Open the file in `append` mode.

   ```
   public class FileWrite {
      public static void write(String message) { 
               PrintWriter out = null;
             try {
                 out = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("output.txt", true), true);
             } catch (IOException e) {
                 // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                 e.printStackTrace();
             }
               out.write(message);
               out.close();
       }

      public static void main(String[] args){
          String lineFromInput = "";
          try {
               System.out.println("Provide the inputs in any number of lines");
               System.out.println("Type \"exit\" in new line when done");
               BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                                   new InputStreamReader(System.in));
               while(!"exit".equals(lineFromInput)){
                  lineFromInput = in.readLine();
                  FileWrite.write(lineFromInput+System.lineSeparator());
               }
               in.close();
           } catch (IOException e) {
               // TODO Auto-generated catch block
               e.printStackTrace();
          }
      }
    }
   ```

**EDIT3:** Your updated program using `Scanner` to read the inputs:

```
        private static HashMap<Integer, Object> shapes = 
                                              new HashMap<Integer, Object>();
        static int i = 0;

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            PrintWriter output = null;
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            try {
                output = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("output.txt"), true);
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                System.err.println("You don't have accress to this file");
                System.exit(1);
            }
            String command = "";
            while(!"quit".equalsIgnoreCase(command)){
                System.out.println("Enter your Command: ");
                command = scanner.next();
                if (command.equalsIgnoreCase("create")) {
                    String type = scanner.next();
                    if (type.equalsIgnoreCase("line")) {
                        double length = scanner.nextDouble();
                        Line l = new Line(length);
                        scanner.nextLine();//flush the previous line
                        String line = scanner.nextLine();
                        output.format("%s", line);
                        shapes.put(i, l);
                        i++;
                    }else if (type.equalsIgnoreCase("circle")) {
                        double radius = scanner.nextDouble();
                        String color = scanner.next();
                        Circle c = new Circle(radius, Colors.valueOf(color));
                        scanner.nextLine();//flush the previous line
                        String line = scanner.nextLine();
                        output.format("%s", line);
                        shapes.put(i, c);
                        i++;
                    }else if (type.equals("rectangle")) {
                        double length = scanner.nextDouble();
                        double width = scanner.nextDouble();
                        String color = scanner.next();
                        Rectangle r = new Rectangle(length, width,
                        Colors.valueOf(color));
                        scanner.nextLine();//flush the previous line
                        String line = scanner.nextLine();
                        output.format("%s", line);
                        shapes.put(i, r);
                        i++;
                    }else if (type.equals("square")) {
                        double length = scanner.nextDouble();
                        String color = scanner.next();
                        Square s = new Square(length, Colors.valueOf(color));
                        scanner.nextLine();//flush the previous line
                        String line = scanner.nextLine();
                        output.format("%s", line);
                        shapes.put(i, s);
                        i++;
                    }
                }else if (command.equals("printbyperimeter")) {
                    Shape[] shapeArray = shapes.values().toArray(new Shape[0]);
                    Arrays.sort(shapeArray);
                            System.out.println("Print in ascending order...");
                    for (int j = 0; j < shapeArray.length; j++) {
                        Shape temp = shapeArray[j];
                        if (temp.getClass().getName().equals("Line")) {
                            System.out.println("Shape: " 
                                    + temp.getClass().getName() + ", Perimeter: "
                                    + temp.getPerimeter());
                                } else {
                            System.out.println("Shape: " 
                                    + temp.getClass().getName() + ", Color: "
                                    + ((Colorable) temp).getColor()
                                    + ", Perimeter: " + temp.getPerimeter());
                                }
                            }
                }else if (command.equals("printbyarea")) {
                    Shape[] shapeArray = shapes.values().toArray(new Shape[0]);
                    System.out.println("Print in random order...");
                    for (int j = 0; j < shapeArray.length; j++) {
                        Shape temp = shapeArray[j];
                        if (!temp.getClass().getName().equals("Line")) {
                            System.out.println("Shape: "
                                    + temp.getClass().getName() + ", Color: "
                                    + ((Colorable) temp).getColor() + ", Area: "
                                    + ((Areable) temp).getArea());
                                }
                        }
                }else if (command.equals("quit")) {
                    scanner.close();
                    System.exit(0);
                }
           }
           output.close();
        }
```

Comment: @DownVoter: Please leave some comment.

Comment: `OutputtStreamReader` doesn't exist.  Nor does `OutputStreamReader`.

Comment: @Makoto: Yes, I know. I made the `t` remark to avoid OP searching for `InputtStreamReader` (with two t(s)). Is that the reason for downvote?

Comment: Yes.  Why would one mislead someone in that manner?  Furthermore, this doesn't address the missing `OutputStreamReader` class.

Comment: @Makoto: What is misleading? I said, it should be `InputStremReader` not `OutputtStreamReader`?? I can see OP also acknowledged and not looking for `OutputtStreamReader` anymore. You have right to vote but I don't think it's right.

Comment: Yes I just updated it. That was a mistake from my own messing around before I posted on SO. It should be inputstreamreader

Comment: @ZAX: Can you please check the value in `lineFromInput` variable by adding `System.out.println(lineFromInput);` before writing to the file to make sure, you have the value, but its not writing in the file.

Comment: My issue is it needs to be able to add several lines to the file, not just one and not just once. The program asks the user for input several times and then gives output several times

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19191/discussion-between-yogendra-singh-and-zax)

Comment: @YogendraSingh I'm there! Thanks!

Comment: @ZAX: Please refer the `EDIT2` section in the answer for multi-line input. If still your file is empty, I need to know, how are you running the program and how are you providing inputs.

Comment: @ZAX: I shared the updated program in the chat room. Did you get a chance to look at that?

Answer (score 2):

Each call to write opens and closes the text file. Each time it is opened it is overwritten, so I would expect only the last thing to be written to appear in the file.

I recommend opening the output file from a constructor, and closing it from a close method.

Comment: `new FileWriter("output.txt", true)` will open the file so that new text will be added at the end.

Comment: If you go that way, do the first open with the second parameter false, to avoid accumulating data from previous runs.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the code.  It works for me.  You just need to change the file path to match where you want the output to go.  I am using a BufferedWriter here which I believe is preferred.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
String lineFromOutput;

try {
    lineFromOutput = in.readLine();
    FileWrite.write(lineFromOutput);
} catch (IOException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
 e.printStackTrace();
}



}

public static class FileWrite {
    private static void write(String message) throws IOException { 
      BufferedWriter out = null;
    try {
        out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(new File("C:\\Users\\Teresa\\Dropbox\\output.txt")));
        //Replace the above line with your path.
        out.write(message);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
      out.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: It has the same problem as my earlier approach. The file is created, but nothing is written in the file

Comment: And I just tried outputting some lines to see if there was anything in outputfromline, by printing in both the try and catch sections, neither printed anything as if they weren't even there

Comment: This code works. Are you changing the file path?  I have tested it.